# strftime( ) doesn't display the seconds correctly

Tags: c, time, formatting, timestamp

I tried strftime( ) to get a formatted time-stamp.

```
char ft[ 256 ];
struct tm *tmp;
strftime( ft, 256, "%D - %T", tmp );
```

My problem is that I get "13/02/60 - 03:07:-17958194" as a result. Is there a way to display the seconds properly? (I'm using Mac OS X and gcc)

Comment: @Brian: The time in 24-hour notation (%H:%M:%S)

Comment: What's with the %S%S%S%S? shouldn't that be only a single %S? Your output also has an extra :. Is this the real output?

Comment: "%S%S%S%S" I should have read my code before I paste it from my editor. This is the real output if you delete this part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using an uninitialized value in the code that you've posted, which would explain why you have this problem.  The following code results in what you're looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char ft[256];
  struct tm *tmp;
  time_t curtime;

  time(&curtime);
  tmp = localtime(&curtime);

  strftime(ft, 256, "%D - %T %s", tmp);
  printf("%s\n", ft);

  return(0);
}
```

Then, compile and run the example:

```
cc -o time_ex time_ex.c
./time_ex
02/26/09 - 11:26:34 1235665594
```

**ETA:** Drop the %s if you just want the local time without UNIX time after it, of course.

Answer (score 3):

"%D - %T" should give you proper results, assuming you want "mm/dd/yy - hh:mm:ss".

If your example is accurate to your usage, you may want to consider giving the function a real time instead of some random address in memory.

Answer (score 1):

%s and %S are different formatting characters.

- %s is the number of seconds since the unix epoch.
- %S is the current time's seconds value (00-60) with a leading 0 for numbers < 10.

Comment: Hah, wow.  I need to change my monospace font.  At a glance in my current font, lower-s and upper-s are nearly indistinguishable.  Meh.  I didn't think to look again until you posted this.  Thank you, though.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't initialising `struct tm *tmp;` with anything - please could you post a complete example?

Comment: This was the complete example, I didn't know how to initialize it.